# Relation between scaling dimension and critical exponents for harmonic peturbations in $O(N)$ Wilson-Fisher (WF) in an old paper

Tags: quantum-field-theory, statistical-mechanics, conformal-field-theory, critical-phenomena

I am reading the paper "Harmonic perturbations of generalized Heisenberg spin systems" (D J Wallace and R K P Zia, 1975) - https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0022-3719/8/6/014/meta . The authors consider an $O(N)$ Wilson-Fisher fixed point. They compute to order $\epsilon^3$ a critical exponent which determines whether an harmonic perturbation of the kind $\phi_{i_1}\phi_{i_2}\ldots\phi_{i_k}N_{i_1\ldots i_k}$ is relevant or irrelevant, where $\phi_i$ is the magnetization and $N_{i_1\ldots i_n}$ projects onto traceless symmetric tensors. I would like to relate the latter to the scaling dimension of the corresponding CFT operator (or, analogously, its RG dimension), but unfortunately I am unable to determine the precise relation from their explanation.

In detail, they claim that the free energy as a function of $\phi_i$ and and the inverse susceptibility $r$ takes the form:
$$F(\phi,r)=\phi^2\Gamma^{(2)}(q=0,r)+
\phi^4\Gamma^{(4)}(0,r)+\ldots+
\phi_{i_1}\phi_{i_2}\ldots\phi_{i_k}\Gamma^{(k)}_{i_1\ldots i_k}(0,r)+\ldots. $$
Here $\phi^2=\phi_i\phi_i$. At the critical poitn $r=\Gamma^{(2)}(0)\rightarrow 0$ and
$$\Gamma^{(k)}_{i_1\ldots i_k}(0,r)\propto r^{\alpha_k}N_{i_1\ldots i_k}.$$
Then they literally say "The relevance or otherwise of the perturbation is  obtained by replacing $\phi$ by the equivalent power $(2-\epsilon+\eta)/[2(2-\eta)]$ of r according to scaling laws and writing" 
$$F(\phi,r)=\phi^2\Gamma^{(2)}(1+vN_{i_1\ldots i_k}\phi_{i_1}\phi_{i_2}\ldots\phi_{i_k}r^{\psi_k}\phi^{-k}+\ldots)$$
where $v$ is some coupling and
$$\psi_k=\alpha_k-1+\frac{(k-2)(2-\epsilon+\eta)}{2(2-\eta)}.$$
The perturbation is relevant if $\psi_k<0$, irrelevant otherwise.

I would like to understand the relation between $\alpha_k$ or, equivalently, $\psi_k$ and $\Delta_k$, the scaling dimension of the field, related to the RG dimension (I believe) as $y_k=d-\Delta_k$. Can someone help me?

Comment: I'm not entirely clear on what the Wallace & Zia paper is doing. However, there are multiple ways to compute the scaling dimension of your operator (and therefore also the quantity $y_k$), and the renormalization constant that needs to be computed is the same which appears in the renormalization of $\Gamma^{(k)}_{i_1 \cdots i_k}$, so it is not surprising that $\psi_k$ and $y_k$ are proportional. I could write an extended answer on how to compute $y_k$ directly if that would be helpful without giving its precise relation to the expressions defined in the paper.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I am aware of how to compute $y_k$ explicitly, but I wanted to use the result of the paper. Anyway, while I still do not know the precise relation between $\psi_k$ and $y_k$ in Wallace and Zia paper, I eventually obtained the results for $\Delta_k=d-y_k$ which I was looking for. If someone is interested, it can be obtained from eq.s 15, 90 and 91 of my paper https://arxiv.org/abs/1909.01269 . (If it is not appropriate to quote a self-reference, I will edit this comment - I just think it may be useful to someone).